# Solving equation $z^2 + 6z + 12 - 4i = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

How would one solve this complex number equation, I have tried substituting $z$ by $a+ib$
but afterwards I am left with a long equation which i do not think should be like that?

$$z^2 + 6z + 12 - 4i = 0$$

Comment: $z^2+bz+c=0$ - solve it using the quadratic formula. You will have to take the square root of a complex number, but that is the only difference from the familiar real case.

Answer (score 2):

The quadratic formula is valid for equations that have complex numbers as coefficients.

Thus, the solutions to
$$z^2+6z+(12-4i)=0$$
are
$$z=\frac{-6\pm\sqrt{36-4(12-4i)}}{2}=\frac{-6\pm\sqrt{-12+16i}}{2}=-3\pm\sqrt{-3+4i}.$$
Note that, unlike for positive real numbers, there isn't an agreed-upon choice of **which** square root of $-3+4i$ the notation
$$\sqrt{-3+4i}$$
stands for, so to say that the solutions to the equation are $z=-3\pm\sqrt{-3+4i}$ just means that the solutions are
$$z=-3+w,\quad z=-3-w$$
where $w$ is one of the two complex numbers with the property that $w^2=-3+4i$. Let me know if you need help finding a $w$.

Comment: There's an error on line five, and every line thereafter.

Comment: @FlybyNight: Thanks for catching that :)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can replace $z$ for $a+ib$.

On simplifying,

$a^2-b^2+2abi+6a+6bi+12-4i=0$

or $(a^2-b^2+6a+12)+(2ab+6b-4)i=0$

and so $a^2-b^2+6a+12=0$ and $2ab+6b-4=0$.

However, directly using the quadratic formula is probably more easier than solving these two simultaneous equations of the second degree.